# J2EE Spring MVC : How to change body content on Interceptor or Filter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to build a backend service with encrypt,
And I need all data (Client to Server and S2C) encrypted transfer on Internet.

How can I change body content on Java Interceptor or Filter?

```
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView mav) throws Exception {
    // I try to change the response body on here.
    // But it seemed can't , I can't read the body out and set new encrypted body back.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept whatever you want from the client-server of the modalAndAttribute, here an example about how I intercept an entity previously rendered to the view call it candidacy

```
@ModelAttribute("candidacy")
public Candidacy bindAbstractOrganizationOnCandidacy(final HttpServletRequest request) throws CandidacyException {
    String discriminator = request.getParameter(CANDIDACY_TYPE);
    Candidacy candidacy = null;
    if (discriminator != null) {
        candidacy = new Candidacy();
        candidacy.setCompany(AbstractCandidacyOrganizationBuilder.buildByDiscriminator(discriminator));
    }
    return candidacy;
}
```

Is that what you need?